# error C2679: binary '<<' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'void' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

Tags: c++, overloading

I'm not sure what the problem is. It gives me the error:
error C2679: binary '<<' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'void' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

I overloaded the << so it shouldn't be giving me this error, right?

```
#ifndef ANIMAL_H_
#define ANIMAL_H_ 
#include <iostream> 
#include <string>
using namespace std;

static int counter;
static int getAnimalCount() { return counter; }

class Animal {
    protected:
       string *animalType;
    public:
       virtual void talk() = 0;
       virtual void move() = 0;
       string getAnimalType() { return *animalType; }

               //PROBLEM RIGHT HERE V

       friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&out, Animal& animal) {
           return out << animal.getAnimalType() << animal.talk() << ", " << animal.move();
       };
       ~Animal() {
           counter--;
           animalType = NULL;
       }
 };
 class Reptile : public Animal { 
     public:
         Reptile() { animalType = new string("reptile"); };
 };
 class Bird : public Animal {
     public:
         Bird() { animalType = new string("bird"); };
 };
 class Mammal : public Animal{
     public:
         Mammal() { animalType = new string("mammal"); };
 };
 #endif /* ANIMAL_H_ */
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`virtual void talk() = 0;` specifies a function with return type `void`. This means it does not return anything. The same happens when you define `Animal::move` as `virtual void move() = 0;`.

`out << animal.getAnimalType() << animal.talk() << ", " << animal.move();` tries to print the result of `animal.talk()` and the result of `animal.move()` - neither of which exists (remember, neither `talk()` nor `move()` return any value!)

Answer (score 2):

Your overloaded `<<` operator looks like this:

```
return out << animal.getAnimalType() << animal.talk() << ", " << animal.move();
```

First of all, the `talk()` and `move()` methods return `void`. You cannot print void.

Comment: getAnimalType() *is* a member function.

Answer (score 0):

Point is at code generator. I have class member Dot.printX(), and in output stream I used `cout<<Dot.printX<<endl;` so that cause an error.

Adding `printX()` will fix a problem!

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

same this happens for this program too

```
#include <iostream>

void UNH(double b)
{
    std::cout << UNH(b) << std::endl;

}
int main()
{
    UNH(5); 
    return 0;
}
```

the thing is void cant take printing value at all. Also for conversion rules, it doesn't work,

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).